# Desaturate tile layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, tiles

I have a OL3 map with one tile and one vector layer. Since the features on the vector layer don't stand out enough against the tile layer in the background, I want to desaturate the tile layer.

I'm aware of [the Hue/Saturation Example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/hue-saturation.html), but this approach works only with WebGL. WebGL in turn does not support vector layers.

**How can I desaturate an OpenLayers 3 tile layer when using the canvas renderer?**

NOTE: I cannot desaturate the tiles on the server, because I don't control the server that hosts the tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Lkpbbr8/

Change chroma to 0%. Raster layer will become desaturated whereas vector layer remain colored.